# How accurate is the solution to this surd question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

[image]

This is a SURD problem, I totally understand step one but not the remaining steps. My question is how did step 2 (as seen in the picture) come about?

Comment: It's clear that $x=3+√8$, $\frac1x=3-√8$, when you add these we get the step

Comment: Just to be clear, the above is one way of doing it. You could also grind through the computation and get the same answer.

Comment: How do you grind through the computation.. I'm curious.. Can u do it? Pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be clear that if $x = 3 + \sqrt{8}$ and $1/x = 3 - \sqrt{8}$, we have $x + 1/x = 6$.

I think the question is more about what ist the intuition behind considering $x + 1/x$ when the question asks for $x^4 + 1/x^4$. The key observation is here that if you use the binomial formula, you get

$$\left ( x + \frac{1}{x} \right )^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2 \cdot x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2$$

and therefore, the expression $x^2 + 1/x^2$ can be easily calculated by

$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = \left ( x + \frac{1}{x} \right )^2 - 2.$$

Since you know the value of $x + 1/x$, the right hand side in the above equation is easily obtained. Now we if have this, a similar argument using the binomial formula lets one comfortably conclude the value of $x^4 + 1/x^4$.

Comment: Thanks Jan.. Now I understand but there's still one part I dontt get... I understand your first and second step... My question is how did you get --2 (minus two) in your third step.. Where is the minus from?

Comment: I just rearranged the terms. My first equation reads $(x + 1/x)^2 = x^2 + 1/x^2 + 2$. Subtract $2$ on both sides and you get $(x + 1/x)^2 - 2 = x^2 + 1/x^2$. Now interchanging the left hand side and the right and side yields $x^2 + 1/x^2 = (x + 1/x)^2 - 2$, which I have written in my second equation.

Comment: Oh wow.. Okay.. Thanks!!

Comment: Please avoid writing "Thanks" in the comments. You can accept my answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Okay,gotcha....